# 'ZipExtFile' object has no attribute 'open'

Tags: python, zip

I have a file `f` that i pulled from a url response:

`<zipfile.ZipExtFile name='some_data_here.csv' mode='r' compress_type=deflate>`

But for some reason i can't do `f.open('some_data_here.csv')`

I get an error saying:
`'ZipExtFile' object has no attribute 'open'`

I'm really confused because isn't that one of the attributes of ZipExtFile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm really confused because isn't that one of the attributes of ZipExtFile?

A `ZipExtFile` object is what you get when you call `open` on a `ZipFile`:

```
>>> import zipfile
>>> z = zipfile.ZipFile('arduino-ide_2.0.3_Linux_64bit.zip')
>>> f = z.open('arduino-ide_2.0.3_Linux_64bit/LICENSE.electron.txt')
>>> f
<zipfile.ZipExtFile name='arduino-ide_2.0.3_Linux_64bit/LICENSE.electron.txt' mode='r' compress_type=deflate>
```

There is no `open` method on a `ZipExtFile` because it's *already* an open file. You can `read` or `readline` from it:

```
>>> f.readline()
b'Copyright (c) Electron contributors\n'
```